# Multiple linear regression with non-numerical dependent data

Tags: python, linear-regression

Basically i am working on a Multiple linear regression problem where i am trying to used 3 independent variables (2 non-numerical, 1 numerical), in order to predict 8 dependent variables (5 of which are numerical and 3 are non-numerical).
So to achieve this i have to use encoding techniques to deal with non-numerical data. Having spent a lot of time on figuring out the code, i am stuck at a simple problem. My code cannot find the 3 dependent variables (non-numerical ones) in the csv file. I have checked the csv file and it contains the label. There is no spelling mistake or white space or case sensitivity issue.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder

# load data
data = pd.read_csv('D:\EMJMD-SMACCs\Thesis\Thesis Work\Recommendation Engine\Experiment.csv')

# Encode categorical variables
enc_cat = ['Building type', 'Building climate', 'Wall Insulation', 'Roof Insulation', 'Window Glazing']
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc_df = pd.DataFrame(enc.fit_transform(data[enc_cat]).toarray())
categories = enc.categories_
new_cols = [f"{col}_{val}" for col, vals in zip(enc_cat, categories) for val in vals]
enc_df.columns = new_cols
data = pd.concat([data, enc_df], axis=1)
data.drop(enc_cat, axis=1, inplace=True)

# Encode dependent variables
label_enc = LabelEncoder()
data['Wall Insulation Encoded'] = label_enc.fit_transform(data['Wall Insulation'])
data['Roof Insulation Encoded'] = label_enc.fit_transform(data['Roof Insulation'])
data['Window Glazing Encoded'] = label_enc.fit_transform(data['Window Glazing'])

# Train multiple linear regression model
X = data[['Building area'] + list(enc_df.columns)]
y = data[['Wall U value', 'Roof U value', 'Wall Insulation Encoded', 'Wall Insulation thickness', 'Roof Insulation Encoded', 'Roof insulation thickness', 'Window U value', 'Window Glazing Encoded']]
model = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)


# Prompt user to enter independent variable values
building_type = input("Enter the building type (e.g. Single family house): ")
building_climate = input("Enter the building climate (e.g. Mediterranean): ")
building_area = float(input("Enter the building area (in square meters): "))

# Encode user input using the same OneHotEncoder object
enc_input = enc.transform([[building_type, building_climate, ' ', ' ', ' ']]).toarray()
enc_input_df = pd.DataFrame(enc_input, columns=new_cols)

# Predict encoded dependent variables for the user input
user_input = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Building area': [building_area]}), enc_input_df], axis=1)
predicted_enc = model.predict(user_input)

# Decode predicted encoded dependent variables
predicted_wall_insulation = label_enc.inverse_transform([int(predicted_enc[0][2])])[0]
predicted_roof_insulation = label_enc.inverse_transform([int(predicted_enc[0][4])])[0]
predicted_window_glazing = label_enc.inverse_transform([int(predicted_enc[0][7])])[0]

# Print predicted values
print("Predicted values for the given input:")
print(f"Wall U value: {predicted_enc[0][0]:.3f}")
print(f"Roof U value: {predicted_enc[0][1]:.3f}")
print(f"Wall Insulation thickness: {predicted_enc[0][3]:.3f}")
print(f"Roof insulation thickness: {predicted_enc[0][5]:.3f}")
print(f"Window U value: {predicted_enc[0][6]:.3f}")
print(f"Wall Insulation: {predicted_wall_insulation}")
print(f"Roof Insulation: {predicted_roof_insulation}")
print(f"Window Glazing: {predicted_window_glazing}")
```

[Snap of the data in the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Pc8.png)

Error i am getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\EMJMD-SMACCs\Thesis\Thesis Work\Recommendation Engine\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3802, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Wall Insulation'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\EMJMD-SMACCs\Thesis\Thesis Work\Recommendation Engine\Code\exppppp.py", line 20, in 
data['Wall Insulation Encoded'] = label_enc.fit_transform(data['Wall Insulation'])
File "D:\EMJMD-SMACCs\Thesis\Thesis Work\Recommendation Engine\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3807, in **getitem**
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "D:\EMJMD-SMACCs\Thesis\Thesis Work\Recommendation Engine\Code\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3804, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Wall Insulation'

Comment: In your code, you drop the `enc_cat` columns, which includes the `'Wall Insulation'` column. So of course it's not going to be located in `data` after that.

Comment: @AlexK Can you please tell me which line i should make modification in my code and what exactly i should add. I didn't completely understand what you said

Comment: I can't say exactly what you should do, because your code is a bit confusing. You are passing the `'Wall Insulation'` column, for example, through both `OneHotEncoder` and `LabelEncoder`. And it's not clear why you are dropping the columns in the `enc_cat` list using `data.drop(enc_cat, axis=1, inplace=True)` when you then are trying to use those columns later for `LabelEncoder` and then to define your `X`. You should review your pipeline and make sure you are doing the right thing with each column.